# JQuery - How to loop through all form inputs?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to get the value of all inputs from a form via JQuery into an array which will be sent via GET through AJAX.

I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
function gatherFormData(){
    $('#formId input, #formId select').each(
    function(index){
        var result = [];
        for(var i =0; i < $(this).length; i++){
        document.write(input.attr('name') + "-" + input.attr('name') + "<br />");
        result.push(input.attr('name'));
        result.push(input.val());
        }
    return result;
    }
    );
}
```

How can I get the values of all of them?

Comment: Try `FORM.find(':input')`

Comment: [`.serializeArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) already does that i.e. `$('#formId').serializeArray()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following way:

```js
var jsonObj = [];
$(":input").each(function(){
 var key = $(this).attr('name');
 var val = $(this).val();
 item = {}
 item [key] = val;

 jsonObj.push(item);
});

console.log(jsonObj);
// Now pass it like jsonObj[0], jsonObj[1]......
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="txtName" value="John" />
  <input type="text" name="email" id="txtEmail" value="john@gmail.com" />
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="active" id="chkIsActive" checked />
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="qweqsac" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks! But I actually want to gather them all into a "get" format to be sent via AJAX.

Comment: Then you need to build an object with all those values.

Comment: Hi Bob, The changed code in the snippet might help you.